# Number of Ring homomorphisms $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_{12}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-homomorphism

How could I determine the number of homomorphisms of rings with identity $1_A$ from $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$? And how this number change if I consider the homomorphisms of rings without the identity element? I've always seen this kind of problem with the homomorphisms of groups from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$, but how can I extend it to unitary and non-unitary rings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general all ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_{m}$ to $\mathbb Z_{n}$ are the functions $f$ satisfying $mf(1)=0$ and $f(1)^2=f(1)$.

So for $m=n=12$, the maps :

$\begin{align}\bar 1 &\mapsto\bar 1\\\bar 1 &\mapsto\bar 5\\\bar 1 &\mapsto\bar 7\\\bar 1 &\mapsto\bar{11}\end{align}\tag*{}$

satisfy these properties.

Why I choose this numbers as the images of $\bar 1$? Because these numbers $(1, 5, 7, 11)$ are less than $12$ and prime to $12$. So each of these number alone can generate the image $\mathbb Z_{12}$.

So these are all ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_{12}$ to $\mathbb Z_{12}$.

Comment: but $1$ and $13$ are congruent in $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$ (?), so the first and the last map are the same

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I've edited it.

Comment: But what are the differences between a unitary and a non-unitary ring?

Comment: I'm not understanding the way you found the homomorphisms that satisfy the conditions you imposed

Comment: Actually for ring homomorphism $f$, firstly it has to be a group homomorphism, right. This fact is encoded by $f(m)=f(1+\cdots +1)=f(1)+\cdots +f(1)=mf(1)$. One extra condition that $f$ has to satisfy in order to be a ring homomorphism is that $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$. So in particular, for $a=b=1$ you see $f(1)=f(1\cdot 1)=f(1)f(1)=f(1)^2$. In Ali's post, he  actually supposed $f(1)=a$.

Comment: Ok... so, first you have found the idempotent elements in the ring, then you have given a description of them, noticing that they map 1 in the invertible elements, right?

Comment: Sure, you first collect the elements of the image whose order divide the order of the domain ring, then the work of finding the idempotents will be reduced.

Comment: Where can I find something about the of the order of the images?

Comment: If $f\colon\mathbb Z_m\to\mathbb Z_n$ and $f(1)=a$, then $m\cdot 1=0\implies mf(1)=f(m\cdot 1)=f(0)=0$ , so order of $f(1)$ divides $m$. Also being an element of $\mathbb Z_n$, $f(1)$ divides $n$. So $f(1)$ is a common divisor of $m$ and $n$. The greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$ is $gcd(m,n)$. So $f(1)$ divides $gcd(m,n)$. So you find those elements in $\mathbb Z_n$ whose orders divide $gcd(m,n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A ring morphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{12} \to \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is uniquely determined by what it does to a generator, say to $1$.

Also, the additive order of the image of $1$ must divide $12$.

How many ring morphisms can you obtain this way?

Answer (score 0):

All ring homomorphisms $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}_n\to\mathbb{Z}_n$ are of the form $\varphi(x)=ax$, and $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism if and only if $a\equiv a^2 \mod n$.

To prove this, assume $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism. Then $a \equiv \varphi(1) \equiv \varphi(1^2)\equiv\varphi(1)^2\equiv a^2 \mod n$.

For the second part, $\varphi(x+y) = a(x + y) = ax + ay = \varphi(x) + \varphi(y)$ is already known. If $a\equiv a^2$, then $\varphi(xy) \equiv axy \equiv a^2xy \equiv axay \equiv \varphi(x)\varphi(y)\mod n$, and this finishes the proof.

Since the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has 4 idempotent elements $(0, 1, 4, 9)$, there are $4$ homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

These articles can be helpful:

[The number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$](http://users.metu.edu.tr/sozkap/461/The%20number%20of%20homomorphisms%20from%20Zn%20to%20Zm.pdf)

[The number of ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_n$](https://ir-library.ku.ac.ke/bitstream/handle/123456789/19273/The%20Number%20of%20Ring%20Homomorphisms%20from%20%E2%84%A4%20%20to%20%E2%84%A4.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)